# 'relevel' only works with (unordered) factors

Tags: r, metafor

```
library(pacman)
pacman::p_load(metafor,readxl,metaviz,MetaAnalyser,rio)
#library(readxl,metaviz,MetaAnalyser,rio)


#Effektstärke
Bor1 <- data.frame(read_excel("Borenstein_1.xls"))

Bor1 <- escalc(measure = "SMD", m1i=mw.t, m2i = mw.c, sd1i = sd.t, sd2i = sd.c, n1i= n.t, n2i= n.c, data= Bor1)


#Heterogenitätstests Fixed/Random-Effects / Test for heterogeneity
fe.mod <- rma(yi = yi, vi = vi, measure = "SMD", method = "FE", slab = Studie, data = Bor1)
forest(fe.mod, showweights = TRUE)

re.mod <- rma(yi = yi, vi = vi, measure = "SMD", method = "DL", slab = Studie, data = Bor1)

forest(re.mod, showweights = TRUE)
confint(re.mod)
predict(re.mod)

#Integration mit kategorialer Variable / Integration categorical variable
Bor2 <- read.delim2("Borenstein_2.txt")
fe.all <- rma(yi=d, vi=var.d, measure="SMD", method="FE", slab=study, data=Bor2)
fe.A <- rma(yi=d, vi=var.d, measure="SMD", method="FE", slab=study,
            subset=group=="a", data=Bor2)

fe.B <- rma(yi=d, vi=var.d, measure="SMD", method="FE", slab=study,
            subset=group=="b", data=Bor2)

#Im Modell mit Kovariable: / Model with categorical variable
fe.mod <- rma(yi=d, vi=var.d, mods= ~group, measure="SMD", method="FE",
              slab=study, data=Bor2)
fe.mod

#Gruppe ‘a’ als Referenzgruppe: / Group a as reference
fe.mod <- rma(yi=d, vi=var.d, mods= **~relevel(group, ref="b")**, measure="SMD", method="FE",
              slab=study, data=Bor2)
re.mod <- rma(yi=d, vi=var.d, mods= ~group, measure="SMD", method="DL",
              slab=study, data=Bor2)


#Meta-Regression
bcg <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, digits=3, data=dat.bcg)
bcg[, -c(1,9)]
```

---

So I am supposed to write a meta-analysis in R but have never used R before. I am a bit overwhelmed.
The code above is working except for the relevel function under group a as reference, in which I want to change the reference group in a subgroup analysis. So I have studies from group a and group b and want to change the reference group.
For the relevel function I get the following error:

*Error in relevel.default(group, ref = "b") :
'relevel' only for (unordered) factors*

Sorry if I posted more code than necessary. I wasn't sure. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20):

The `relevel()` function only works on factors, but variable `group` is not a factor, just a string/character variable. So just do `mods= ~ relevel(factor(group), ref="b")` if you want to make level `b` the reference group.

Comment: Many thanks that solved it. Who would have thought that writing factor() turns variables into a factor ;-) Learned sth today.